# String replacement in excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I want to remove `%` and replace with a string, and to remove space and replace it with under score.

This is what I have done so far:

```
# Open Excel file from a user imput
import xlrd, xlwt
filename = raw_input("Enter Excel file name with extension (.xls) and path")
oldbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
newbook = xlwt.Workbook()

# For all the sheets in the workbook
for sheetname in oldbook.sheet_names():
    oldsheet = oldbook.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    newsheet = newbook.add_sheet(sheetname)

    # For all the rows and all the columns in an excel
    for ii in range(oldsheet.nrows):
        for jj in range(oldsheet.ncols):
            # Replace
            range.replace("%", "Perc")

# Save the file in a desired location with the desired name
savelocation = raw_input("Enter a new path and file name with extension (.xls) to save the new Excel spread sheet ")
newbook.save(savelocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

One advice, read cell data into a string and then manipulate it.

Try this: (Unfortunately I cannot run it at the moment)

```
# Open Excel file from a user imput
import xlrd, xlwt
filename = raw_input("Enter Excel file name with extension (.xls) and path")
oldbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
newbook = xlwt.Workbook()

# For all the sheets in the workbook
for sheetname in oldbook.sheet_names():
    oldsheet = oldbook.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    newsheet = newbook.add_sheet(sheetname)

    # For all the rows and all the columns in an excel
    for ii in range(oldsheet.nrows):
        for jj in range(oldsheet.ncols):
            # Replace
            CellString=str(oldsheet.cell(ii, jj).Value)
            CellString=CellString.replace("%", "Perc")
            CellString=CellString.replace(" ", "_")
            newsheet.write(ii, jj, CellString)
# Save the file in a desired location with the desired name
savelocation = raw_input("Enter a new path and file name with extension (.xls) to save the new Excel spread sheet ")
newbook.save(savelocation)
```

Comment: i ran the code as you said and nothing happened. i dont get an error but the values whwere not replaced

Comment: Yes i get the spreadsheet with all my numbers formatted as string but they are not changed.... the % are still symbols and empty spaces in the excel are not subbed with underscore.

Comment: The `replace` method does not modify strings in-place.  (Actually, Python strings *cannot* be modified in-place.)  Instead, the method returns a new string.  So you need to have something to receive the return value (which could be the same name if you like).

Comment: True! I don't know what I was thinking yesterday. Thanks a lot, now it is corrected.

Comment: i still dont get it. i added another variable to received the replace but no result. how do i put the replaced value back where they belong ?